# decrypt the code in portuguese

Tags: decryption

A friend of mine sent me this encrypted message and I have no idea how to decrypt it!

And btw, to make things worse, the message is in portuguese, not english!!

Here:
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Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is encrypted using XOR encryption, with the key: `0x123f48233c3b2b150d5d097405097a30381e546240`. When I decrypt the first few bytes of your message using that key, I get

### ET Telefone de casa!!

I'm not sure what that means in Portuguese... But, here is what I did to decrypt the message:

First, convert the first few bytes of the message from base64 to hex:

```
echo -n 'V2tod1lXTnNiM2xUYWxaU1ltNUNh' | base64 -d | xxd -p
```

This produces:

```
576b687759574e7362336c54616c5a53596d354361
```

Now, use python to XOR this with the key `0x123f48233c3b2b150d5d097405097a30381e546240`:

```
python3 -c "print (hex(0x576b687759574e7362336c54616c5a53596d354361 ^ 0x123f48233c3b2b150d5d097405097a30381e546240))"
```

This produces:

0x45542054656c65666f6e6520646520636173612121

Now, convert this hex to bytes, and ascii-decode the bytes:

```
echo -n '45542054656c65666f6e6520646520636173612121' | xxd -r -p
```

This produces:

```
ET Telefone de casa!!
```

By any chance, are you expecting a call from a famous 80's movie alien?

Comment: The duplicate of this was closed. Why answer an off-topic question a 2nd time?

Comment: @schroeder  I was trying to make a point about these types of questions that often appear here, where someone posts a bunch of gibberish and asks us to decrypt it (without any info as to the type of encryption that was used, how the keys were generated, etc).  The point is, these questions cannot be answered, because there are an infinite number of answers to these types of questions, because you can make the gibberish decrypt to anything you want, given no information about the encryption method, keys, etc..  I know the answer was a bit satirical, sorry if it was out of line.